# Reference for discrete convex functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, discrete-optimization

On page 4 of this [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.472.9343&rep=rep1&type=pdf), the author defines a convex function on $\mathbb{Z}$ as follows. This function is the ones that verifies the condition $2f(x) \leq f(x+1) + f(x-1)$. He also said that for some $x_0\in\mathbb{Z}$, $f(x_0)$ is the global minimum of $f$ if and only if $f(x_0) \leq \min\{f(x_0 - 1), ~ f(x_0 + 1)\}$. I successfully proved this statement.

Moreover, I also proved that the global minimum is reached at only one point $x_0$ if and only if $f(x_0) < \min\{f(x_0 - 1), ~ f(x_0 + 1)\}$. However this is not stated in the paper.

I want to use both statements in my personal paper and I think that those results are certainly proved somewhere (in a book for example) and I can simply cite this reference. But I do not find such a reference.

Comment: Did you try [Murota's book](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9780898718508)? I do not have it in my office right now, so I unfortunately can't check.

Comment: Thanks @Guyslain. Yes I checked the book but I just found what I stated above. The paper above is even written by Murota but he focuses more on L-convex and M-convex. I am just interested in the case of a uni-variate function.